# Несколько окон редактирования Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo

Используется Kendo Grid.
Существует ли возможность поднимать на редактирование больше чем один ряд из таблицы одновременно?
Скрин:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5skv1TiUA52VllHTzFRVFRFeWM/view?usp=sharing
На данный момент, если попытаться открыть еще одно окно, то первое закроется.

Answer (score 1):

Возможность существует - никто не запрещает вам реализовать такой функционал самостоятельно. Сам же кендо грид не предоставляет такой функциональности из коробки.